# html form with two actions depending on submit button

Tags: html, forms, noscript

similar to this question, but for when you do not have control of the backend: [HTML form with multiple "actions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660734/html-form-with-multiple-actions)

supposed i have an UI:

```
[input field       ] [button A] [button B]
```

let's say button A should go to `://another.company.com/edit?input_field` and button B must go to `://yet.another.company.com/delete?confirmation=yes&input_field`

I already have the javascript solution in place. and for no-script users i am creating a single target script that reads which submit button was pressed and respond with a HTTP 302 to the right url, so i can make it work with a single html form action... but is there a solution that uses **only HTML**? Don't care if it is not html4 compatible.

*meta comment: please, do not add answers saying "no". I already know that. this is an exploratory question to see if there is any clever trick or obscure standard. I know the consensus is that it is not possible already and my question even includes the most practical work-around already. thank you!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the `formaction` attribute of the `<input>`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button

Comment: use an onclick function of the buttons to dynamically alter the action attribute of the form before submitting it.

Comment: @gavgrif The OP specifically says no script. `onclick` is a script. From looking at the docs, this appears to be the correct answer.

Comment: Interesting. but has all sort of odd implementations. In safari for example, if i move the hidden inputs as part of the target url, so as to not send those fields on both forms actions, when i submit it, it strips all the query values and add only the ones present in the form's inputs.