# Two actions on the same form button

Tags: forms, submit, action

I have seen something similar somewhere around here but that solution does not completely apply to me. This guy had two button doing different things as I have only one button doing two actions at once (one for reCaptcha and the other for email submission). After extensive Google searches with no solution I'm at a loss.

Comment: you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660734/html-form-with-multiple-actions

Comment: That's one of the one that I saw before but he has 2 buttons as I only have one, hence the dilemna.